# Uninstall RedHat and start Windows 7 instantly

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, redhat-enterprise-linux

On my laptop I have installed Windows 7 on a partition.

A friend on mine installed RedHat Linux on a different partition and now when I open my laptop appears a boot screen to choose the operating system. This is from linux instalation and not from Windows.

Can I remove the linux installation and make my laptop start automatically in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, grab your Windows 7 install disk and run a repair on the disk - this should fix the bootloader, which will remove the OS menu when you boot the laptop and make it automatically boot windows.

To free up the space, you can then use either the windows 7 partition manager, your favorite partition manager, or the partition manager from your favorite Linux live CD to delete the Red hat partition ( write the the size of your windows partition so you don't accidentally delete it - it might also be labeled "ntfs" in the partition editor). The windows 7 partition manager has the bonus of labeling your partitions with drive letters to help prevent you from deleting the wrong one.

After you delete the Red Hat partition, resize any other partitions to take up the newly freed space if you don't already have plans for it.

Comment: For the deletion part of the partition I know how to do it. But my question is that making a repair of Windows will be enough to fix the bootloader?

Comment: It should. If it does not, then insert your install disk and go to System Recovery Options, open the console, and try `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot`